# ASP.NET MVC Retaining Data from View to Controller Using Strongly Typed ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I apologise in advance for asking a question that has been answered before but i am still a novice and find it difficult to apply solutions to my own problem.

I have a view model that i populate some data on creating and then intend to fill with data using a cascading drop down list (i cant use any client side scripts)

```
public class StudentPortalModel
{
    public SelectList LocationListModel { get; set; }
    public SelectList ResidenceListModel { get; set; }
    public int ChosenLocation { get; set; }
    public int ChosenBlock { get; set; }
    public int ChosenFlat { get; set; }
    public int ChosenRoom { get; set; }
    public int ChosenResidence { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action in a controller which populates the viewmodel with some lists that i use for drip down menus as so:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SelectResidence()
        {


            List<Location> objLocationList = (from data in db.Locations select data).ToList();
            SelectList objLocationModelData = new SelectList(objLocationList, "LocationId", "LocationName", 0);


            List<Residence> objResidenceList = (from data in db.Residences select data).ToList();
            SelectList objResidenceModelData = new SelectList(objResidenceList, "ResidenceId", "BlockNumber", 0);


            StudentPortalModel objStudentPortalModel = new StudentPortalModel();
            objStudentPortalModel.LocationListModel = objLocationModelData;
            objStudentPortalModel.ResidenceListModel = objResidenceModelData;


            return View(objStudentPortalModel);
        }
```

I want the model data sent to the view to be returned back to the controller

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectLocation", "StudentPortal", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChosenLocation, Model.LocationListModel, "---Select Location---")

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

i want all the data i post to the view to be retained when sent back to the HttpGet method.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SelectLocation(StudentPortalModel testPortalInstance)
        {
            List<Location> objLocationList = (from data in db.Locations select data).ToList();
            SelectList objLocationModelData = new SelectList(objLocationList, "LocationId", "LocationName", 0);


            List<Residence> objResidenceList = (from data in db.Residences select data).Where(i => i.LocationId == testPortalInstance.ChosenLocation).DistinctBy(x => x.BlockNumber).ToList();
            SelectList objResidenceModelData = new SelectList(objResidenceList, "ResidenceId", "BlockNumber", 0);

            testPortalInstance.LocationListModel = objLocationModelData;
            testPortalInstance.ResidenceListModel = objResidenceModelData;

            return View("SelectResidence", testPortalInstance);

        }
```

As you all probably know, the only data that gets sent back is ChosenLocation as that is sent back when the end user picks it from the drop down list, everything else is empty

Essentially i need a way of retaining what options the user is choosing for each drop down list. This allows me to narrow down what room a user wishes to pick till i am able to decipher a single room from a table and assign it to a user.

My biggest problem is I cant seem to find the viewmodel data I send to the view and assign it to the same value to send back. when I post back to the controller everything is empty meaning I have to recreate data.

I apologise for my rambling, I put it down to the fact I have only been programming a month.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If you use `Html.HiddenFor(...)` inside the form declaration that'll allow the other information to get posted when ChosenLocation does. (Sorry if this isn't helpful, the way i'm understanding your question it should be, but I'm having troubles focusing right now haha).

Comment: Hi Shelby. Thank you for your reply. I did mean to add that i did try Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LocationListModel) etc it would either error out or when it did return to the controller it was stil empty. this seemd to be because m.LocationListModel in the view was empty. i couldnt seem to find the populated data anywhere to assign it back.

Comment: In order to have model binding automatically handle a complex object, you have to map each of it's properties to a hidden. So something like `Html.HiddenFor(x => x.LocationListModel.property)` which I believe bdarrow is getting at.

Comment: Thanks again Shelby. i cant seem to find a .property or something similar to send back the data. im sure there is a way im just unaware of it.

Comment: Are you using multiple forms to handle data for one model?  That's probably the crux of your issue.  MVC binds model data in a form to it's own model instance.  In short each Form tag get's a new instance of the model.  Ideally you should do everything for that model in one form element, or split your model up into multiple models, one for each form.  For the easiest and most elegant way to handle it.

Comment: Hi Ryios. Yes i am using multiple forms through the use of partial views. This seemed to be the only way i could implement a cascading dropdownlist with submit buttons for each section. Thats why i was hoping i could pass the existing viewmodel data to the new instance of viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really clear why you would not want to use javascript/jquery (it would give much better performance) but you will need to pass the selected values to each GET method from the relevant POST method. Assuming the first step is to choose a location, then a residence, your controller methods would be

```
public ActionResult SelectResidence()
{
  List<Location> locations = (from data in db.Locations select data).ToList();
  StudentPortalModel model = new StudentPortalModel()
  {
    LocationListModel = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "LocationName")
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Note there is no point generating a `SelectList` for `ResidenceListModel` since its not used in the first view which will be

```
@model StudentPortalModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) // no need to add parameters
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChosenLocation, Model.LocationListModel, "---Select Location---")
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

which will post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectResidence(StudentPortalModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // repopulate locations and return view
  }
  return RedirectToAction("SelectResidence", new { locationID = model.ChosenLocation });
}
```

which will redirect to

```
public ActionResult SelectResidence(int locationID)
{
  List<Residence> residences = (from data in db.Residences select data).Where(i => i.LocationId == locationID).ToList();
  StudentPortalModel model = new StudentPortalModel()
  {
    ChosenLocation = locationID,
    ResidenceListModel = new SelectList(residences, "ResidenceId", "BlockNumber")
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

whose view will be

```
@model StudentPortalModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenLocation)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ChosenResidence, Model.ResidenceListModel , "---Select Residence---")
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

which will post back to

```
public ActionResult SelectResidence(StudentPortalModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // repopulate residences based on the value of model.ChosenLocation and return view
  }
  // your model now contains values for both ChosenLocation and ChosenResidence 
}
```

Similarly if you then need to go to a view to choose a room you would redirect to (say) `public ActionResult SelectResidence(int locationID, int residenceID)`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Stephen. The reason i have chosen to avoid any scripting language is because the solution needs to work on a multitude of devices and i cant guarantee that all with have the ability to display javascript etc. Especially for those using accessibility features on their device. I was reliably informed that my best bet was to code the whole site without any. That being thank you so much for the reply, it looks like the perfect solution to my cascading list. I might go back to the powers that be and see if i can perhaps take it further

Comment: Pleasure, but you really should test the answer you accepted. Apart from the fact there is no such thing as `@Html.RenderChildAction` (its `@Html.Action()`) you should never pass a model in route parameters using `new { model = Model }`(if the model contains any properties which are complex objects or collections it will fail).

Comment: My apologies. I did find the model = Model worked in my solution, but like you say, i have to make sure all select lists are populated each time else it will fail. Do you happen to know a better solution at all? Again apologies, i have only been working on MVC for a couple of weeks to know very little in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: That's only because your model contains only value types. It's simply bad practice to send back the model as a route parameter. And you definitely do not want all select lists populated - only one at a time (for the page you are on). Apart from the major performance hit, consider your second page (to select residences). You only want to allow the user to select a residence based on the previously selected location. If you were to display a dropdownlist for both locations and residences, if the user picked a different location, the residence dropdown would not be updated!

Answer (score 1):

Partial views, should make use of

```
@Html.RenderChildAction
```

Which is a method on the Html Helper you use in your razor views.

Your controller methods should be decorated with 
    [ChildActionOnly]

Which is an attribute that makes it so MVC routes the action in a way where it can only be called via RenderChildAction, which prevents people from going to it's url in their browser.

Secondly, you should be passing your models instance to the view on each step of the cascade.

```
return Partial(theModel);
```

or 
    return Partial("somePartialView", theModel);

Those returns would be example returns from controller Actions that return an ActionResult type.

Finally, your form tags can pass your model to the postback.  MVC will automatically JSON serialize it and JSON deserialize it for you, so no need to have tons of hidden tags (maybe in older versions of MVC, but I know this works in mvc 4+).

Here is an example partial view:

```
@model StudentPortalModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetSelection", "StudentPortal", new { model = Model}, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    //Do Form Stuff Here
}
```

Notice above I am passing the model as a route data object... MVC will serialize it to json, post it in the post data, then the controller will deserialize it automatically into the model parameter because it's an anonymous object who's model property and json type info matches the name of the "model" parameter on the controller action.

Example controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSelection(StudentPortalModel model)
{
    return View("NextCascade", Model)
}
```

Now, I didn't use ChildAction only on the above, because you want to be able to post to this.  [ChildActionOnly] is for the Action that loads your partial view, not for the action it is posting back to, those get [HttpPost].

The three attributes in total are:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
```

You can use both HttpGet and HttpPost on the same action, but that is the default.  In other words if you leave off the attributes all together it will route for get and post requests.  Put if you only put HttpGet it will not route for Post Requests (you can't post to it), etc.

Now, let's say that PartialView is called StudentSelection:

There should be a parent action on the controller that returns it initially on the get request (first load) decorated with [ChildActionOnly].  And you should use @Html.RenderChildAction to render that partial view on that action.

Comment: As a note, in MVC, when you don't specify the name of a view in a return like "return Partial(model)".  It assumes the view's file name matches the name of the controller action.  So if your action is called SetLocation, it will try to load a partial view called "SetLocation.cshtml" unless you manually tell it the name of your view via "return Partial("someView", model);

Comment: thank you for all your help Ryios. Im going to go away and try and take it all in and implement it into my solution and hopefully finally get it up and running properly. I really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Model in the post action should have fields that match the input name's in your form that the user fills out. That allows the default MVC model binding to set the user's chosen values to the fields in your StudentPortalModel.

Comment: Hi bdarrow and thanks for the reply. most of the fields are not populated by the user and once they are populated once the next time they go to the view they will not be entered again so i am unable to just have text boxes etc to fill the viewmodel.